# PHP json object give wrong answer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have 3 rows in my db table but when i ask my data with ajax i have 6 lines.
How is this possible ?

in the first 3 ajax calls i have the full db info. and in the next 3 ajax calls i have the right info what i ask in the php for loop

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=projectmobilewebappstest;charset=utf8', 'eclipse', 'eclipse');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM poll');
$query->execute();

$result = $query -> fetchAll();

foreach( $result as $row ) {

     $result[] = array('poll' => $row['poll']
                    ,'Yes' => $row['Yes']);
}

echo json_encode($result);


var form =  $.ajax({
    url: "server.php/lijst",
    type: "post",

    dataType: "json",
    encode: true
})

form.done(function (response) {

   console.log(response[3].Yes)
   $("#mydata").html("");

   for(var i = 0; i < response.length;i++)
   {
        console.log(response[i])
        $("#mydata").append(response[4].poll);
        $("#mydata").append("</br>");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing something confusing here:

```
 foreach( $result as $row ) {

  $result[] = array('poll' => $row['poll']
                    ,'Yes' => $row['Yes']);

 }
```

Comment: ah ok and how can i get all my db polls in objects and send them with json to my jquery ajax ?

Comment: simply use another variable `$result_new = array(...)`

Answer (score 0):

here is a example may be help you

```
$id_user=$_POST['id_user'];
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ailyan', 'root', '');
     $req = $bdd->prepare('select  *  from event where id_user = ?');
    $req->execute(array($id_user));
    //$_SESSION['id']

       $response["events"] = array();

      while(  $donnees = $req->fetch()){
        $endroits = array();
        $endroits ['titre']=$donnees['titre'];
        $endroits ['date']=$donnees['date'];


        array_push($response["events"], $endroits);
       }

     print  json_encode($response);
```

the rest :

```
 $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"traitement/event/recuperer_livraison.php",
      data:{id_user:id_user},
      success:function(data){

       var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

       jQuery.each(obj["events"], function(index, value) {

           console.log(value.titre);
           console.log(value.date);

  })

  }
});
```